# Update google blobstore or cloud storage incrementally?

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I am working on an app wherein users will create a data object and upload it to storage. They will then download it later, make some changes, and upload those changes (as a patch to the original data). Is there a way to use the blobstore or cloud storage to upload the patch and have it applied so that my users do not have to upload the whole data object again (which can grow quite large)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't issue incremental updates to data in Blobstore or Cloud Storage. To apply a patch, you will have to apply it yourself and overwrite the data in the blob or object. Relevant information is below.

From the [Concepts and Terminology section](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/getting-startedv1#intro) of the Google Cloud Storage docs:

> Objects are immutable, which means that an uploaded object cannot
>   change throughout its storage lifetime. An object's storage lifetime
>   is the time between successful object creation (upload) and successful
>   object deletion. In practice, this means that you cannot make
>   incremental changes to objects, such as append operations or truncate
>   operations. However, it is possible to overwrite objects that are
>   stored in Google Cloud Storage because an overwrite operation is in
>   effect a delete object operation followed immediately by an upload
>   object operation. So a single overwrite operation simply marks the end
>   of one immutable object's lifetime and the beginning of a new
>   immutable object's lifetime.

From the [Blobstore Introduction section](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Introducing_the_Blobstore):

> Blobs can't be modified after they're created, though they can be
>   deleted. Each blob has a corresponding blob info record, stored in the
>   datastore, that provides details about the blob, such as its creation
>   time and content type. You can use the blob key to fetch blob info
>   records and query their properties.