# Modifying blobs in AppEngine Blobstore

Tags: file, google-app-engine, mapreduce, blobstore

I need to provide clients with a way to perform the following write-operation on blobs in the AppEngine BlobStore (or maybe on files in Google Cloud Storage instead, if it's easier):

Starting at offset *X*, delete *Y* bytes and insert the following bytes: *[z0, z1, z2, ...]*

For example, if the blob contains the following data:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

I want to allow a client to say "starting at offset 3, replace 5 bytes with [a, b, c, d], after which the blob looks like this:

[0, 1, 2, a, b, c, d, 8, 9, 10, 11]

Is there some way to, for example, use the mapreduce API to tell it "copy X bytes from this blob, then append this data (maybe stored in another blob), and then copy the rest of this blob starting at offset X+Y"?

Or do I have to do this manually by reading the original blob and building a new one from it, performing all operations in 32MB-chunks since that is the request-size-limit? If so, can I expect this to yield somewhat reasonable performance, or are BlobStore up-/downloads to a request handler really slow for large data blocks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update google blobstore or cloud storage incrementally?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346295/update-google-blobstore-or-cloud-storage-incrementally)

Comment: Check the above question.. it's basically solves your concerns: in short you cannot change/update, you'll have to delete and create a new one

Comment: @Lipis Correct... I was just wondering if there is some API (like mapreduce for example) that can assist me in doing this re-create/delete in a more efficient way than for me to read and write raw data to the blobs directly myself.